# [android][python] open image from absolute path in localhost

Tags: android, python, django

- I have a comic reader project with **android client** and **python-django server**. Server will return responses in json format to client.
- When client send request : http://localhost/ComicReader/chapter?chap_id=1 , server responses to client : `{"images":[{id:1,"real_path":"/home/Project/Images/1.jpg"},{id:2,"real_path":"/home/Project/Images/2.jpg"}]}`
- My question is : can android client load an image with url `/home/Project/Images/1.jpg` directly or I have to write a function in django server to open that file than response to client? If both is wrong, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course the client can't load a file on the server via its file path. And you definitely shouldn't write a function that serves arbitrary files via their path; think of the potential security implications (what if someone requests your settings file with your db credentials, for example).

You shouldn't be sending a file path in the response at all; instead, your JSON needs to include a URL that serves the file.

Answer (score 0):

as i know you should pass full image url to your loader like Glide or Picasso or Volley.